# Scrollable BackGround Image with text input fields using Java

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jpanel

I'm pretty new to Java and have been stuck for hours trying to figure out how to do the following...

I would like to create a Java program that shows a panel (has a background image that is scrollable) that contains input boxes.  Think of a panel that shows at 800by800, but the image is more like 2000x2000, with input boxes all over.  As you scroll, nothing should move.

I'd be very greatful if anyone can point me the right direction or has a sample piece of code that they would share.

Thank You!

Comment: Take a look a [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a JScrollPane: [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)

Comment: I've tried using scrollpanes, jlabel for the background image, overriding the paint component, etc...  I just can't get any combination to work.  Every time I get one thing solved, something else doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, should of made myself more clear, using as a background would be impossible as far as I know. You will have to add a JPanel to that JScrollPane and use that as your new background, then add objects to that JPanel.